# Re-Serialize a C# Dataset through an XSD to a XML file

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I’m deserialising an XML file through an XSD in to a C# dataset.

The subsequent datatables are then bulk copied to a T-SQL DB.

The data is then validated and subtly transformed.  No column names are changed.  No relational integrity is set on the DB.

I’d like to know if it’s possible to repackage the tables back into a dataset and then pass the dataset back through the XSD to a xml file?

I can write the dataset out through the XSD to an XML file but it does not reflect the nesting of the XSD.  I’ve added datarelations based upon inferred FK’s but this is still not yielded the requited results.

I then tried adding relation.nested but the complicated nature of the XSD/XML causes the following error  “The same table 'SomeTable' cannot be the child table in two nested relations.”

I’ve looked at many solutions around nesting and datarelations but the XSD and XML are very complicated and therefore falls outside the remit of many examples.

Open to any suggestions but ideally, I’d like it to be as dynamic as possible with as little hardcoding as possible.

I have had some relatively small success with a SQL For XML solution.  I built a config table (over 2000 entries) with all the mappings. Then added the table and mapping to variables and cursor'd my way through them and building the query dynamically as I went. It kind of worked but the code base was too convoluted and not particularly supportable.

A few people have suggested XLST but I don’t have that kind of time.

Many thanks for your time.

Update, here is how i'm trying to apply the relation:

```
 static void ApplyRelation(SqlConnection connection, DataSet dataSet, string tableName, string schemaName)
    {


        string query = $@"
            SELECT child.name AS ParentTableName,
               childCol.name AS ParentColumnName,
               parent.name AS ChildTableName,
               parentCol.name AS ChildColumnName
               FROM
                   sys.foreign_keys fk
                   JOIN sys.tables parent ON fk.parent_object_id = parent.object_id
                   JOIN sys.tables child ON fk.referenced_object_id = child.object_id
                   JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
                   JOIN sys.columns parentCol ON parentCol.object_id = parent.object_id AND parentCol.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
                   JOIN sys.columns childCol ON childCol.object_id = child.object_id AND childCol.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id
               WHERE
                   parent.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('{schemaName}') AND child.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('{schemaName}') AND Child.name = '{tableName}'";
        // Execute the query
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Iterate through the results
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string parentTableName = reader["ParentTableName"].ToString();
                    string parentColumnName = reader["ParentColumnName"].ToString();
                    string childTableName = reader["ChildTableName"].ToString();
                    string childColumnName = reader["ChildColumnName"].ToString();
                    // Check if both parent and child tables are already loaded in the DataSet
                    if (dataSet.Tables.Contains(parentTableName) && dataSet.Tables.Contains(childTableName))
                    {
                        DataTable parentTable = dataSet.Tables[parentTableName];
                        DataTable childTable = dataSet.Tables[childTableName];
                        // Find parent and child columns
                        DataColumn parentColumn = parentTable.Columns[parentColumnName];
                        DataColumn childColumn = childTable.Columns[childColumnName];
                        // Create DataRelation and add to DataSet
                        DataRelation relation = new DataRelation($"{parentTableName}_{childTableName}", parentColumn, childColumn);
                        relation.Nested = true;
                        //dataSet.EnforceConstraints = true;
                        dataSet.Relations.Add(relation);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Example of output]

Comment: How bad is it? You could do a FOR XML thing directly from SQL Server perhaps

Comment: Hi, tried that.  About 50 tables all nested and reused.  I built a config table with all the mapping.  Then added the table and mapping to variables and cursor'd my way through them and building the query dynamically as i went.  It kinda worked but the code base was too convoluted.  It's a non-starter for me.

Comment: Sounds pretty easy to be honest, and you probably don't even need the cursor, how did the mapping look?

Comment: The mapping table had over 2000 entries.  Each element and attribute for the XSD was mapped in it.  It's not very supportable and is the absolute last resort.

Comment: Post the code, tables and transformations, don't describe them. `pass the dataset back through the XSD to a xml file` doesn't make sense - XSD is a schema, not a transformation. You can already save a DataSet or DataTable to XML and if you have a typed dataset, it will have the same schema. The original dataset already uses that schema. `I don’t have that kind of time.` you already spent that time by creating 2K mapping entries. You may not need them at all though.

Comment: For the purposes of clarity, I want to “frame” the output dataset with the XSD.  
As the data in the SQL tables was already “framed” using the same XSD I, perhaps naively, assumed it could be possible to export it from the SQL tables, back into a dataset (with nested relations based upon PK and FK relations) and then “framed” by the XSD.  Hope that makes it clearer.
The code is sensitive as is the XML and XSD.  Apologies but it’s the nature of my job.  This is more of a theoretical pursuit to determine if I’m going down the correct route.

Comment: The mapping table was very easy to create based upon sys tables.  But as I said, it’s a far from elegant solution.
XLST is time consuming as I don’t understand it.

Comment: "still not yielded the requited results." what *do* you get? And what exactly do you want? Please show an example.

Comment: Your first statement does not make any sense "I’m deserialising an XML file through an XSD in to a C# dataset."  The output of deserialization is c# classes, not a dataset.  So how do you get the dataset?

Comment: I see two ways offhand: [OPENXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) + [FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) or [SqlDataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) + DataSet.

Comment: @Charlieface – if I don’t turn on nesting , then it will produce a XML file.  But not nested and bears little relation to the XSD.  Can’t show example, data too sensitive

Comment: @ jdweng – The extraction layer is an XML file that is sent to a dataset and the XSD file is used in ReadXMLSchema

Comment: @Alexander Petrov any end-to-end examples?

Comment: Show a small sample with the data obfuscated. We need a [mcve] otherwise we can't help.

Comment: @Charlieface done, that should be nested

Comment: As text not images please

Comment: @Charlieface you should be fine with that screen image.  I think it shows the issue i'm up against.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14868997) and https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode Images are discouraged. For example, I am not going to even bother trying to solve your issue because I can't test it against yuor XML, because I can't copy it. There's no way I'm going to manually type out so much XML. A minimal XML *as text* showing the issue is necessary.

Comment: @Charlieface To be honest, i'm not sure what copying the XML would do to assist you.  As i mentioned above, this is a theoretical exercise that is looking more for ideas as opposed to resolutions.  From all the suggestions i can see what i'm trying to achieve is perhaps a step too far,

Comment: I would not use XML Serialization.  Instead use the Dataset ReadXml Method which will create a DataTable for each XElement under Root.  Then save the DataTable to the Database.  The reverse will give same as what you started with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.readxml?view=net-8.0#system-data-dataset-readxml(system-xml-xmlreader)

Comment: @Jdweng i wish that was the case.  With very simple XSD/XML structures this is possible.

Comment: I agree.  Been saying that for years that the ReadXml() method does not work with complex XML.  But why not use it in this case where it will work.